# Do I have to book my tickets before applying to E-Visa to India?

Tags: visas, tickets, india, e-visas

I am applying for E-visa to visit India. Now, while everything else looks fine, I am confused about a particular detail. I know my tentative travel dates but I have not booked my tickets yet. Now, given that, while filling up the form, I see them asking me following question:

`Date of arrival in India` and `Date of Departure from India`.

I am talking about the form that I have fill in on this page:

https://cibtvisas.com/india-evisa
Please note that they are not asking me dates for which I am seeking the visa but asking me particular dates assuming I know the dates.

My thinking was that I am planning to go to India sometime in December 1st week and coming back end of December and was hoping to say "Give me visa between December 1 and December 31st" and I will wrap up my travels between those dates.

Now, does this mean that I can not apply for visa without booking the tickets? If so, what happens if I book tickets and my visa gets denied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the link you have posted, but this is the official website for the Indian eVisa https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html

The official website will ask you about the date of arrival, the port of entry and duration of stay. However, you can arrive on a different date as long as it falls within the duration/validity they have granted you.

Also, you don't have to book your ticket before applying to the eVisa.

The aforementioned is based on my experience.

Answer (score 1):

In 2017, I traveled to India on an eVisa, and did not have my ticket booked before my application.

You can also see the sample form [here](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/images/SampleForm.pdf), and it's not required.